# Creating dynamic objects for quiz questions Flash CS4, AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I'm making a flash quiz which will have a series of questions. Each question will have a button which will read the question out. As well as 4 buttons (probably MC's), that the user will click to answer. Each question is a different sound clip and a different set of answers.

Problem is, I need to do it dynamically so I can pick a random sound clip from the library, and 4 random buttons. One of which will be the correct answer. So far I have manged to work out how to create dynamic instances of an object and display it in a random location:

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    var appleMovie:appleMc    = new appleMc();       
    appleMovie.x = +Math.random()*50;
    appleMovie.y = +Math.random()*50;

    this.addChild(appleMovie);
}
```

I can grab random values from an array of movieClip names like:

```
var fruit = new Array("apple", "pear", "grape", "lemon");
var randomValue:Number  =  Math.random()*1;
fruit[randomValue];
```

But this doesn't seem to help when wanting different objects dynamically. Am I going about this the correct way? Should the answer buttons be movie clips that generate their own random graphic as the image? I'm a bit lost on this one. Any help would be really appreacited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like your array of name, `new Array("apple", "pear", "grape", "lemon");` you can create an Array filled with Class objects.

```
var randMcs:Array=[AppleMc,LemonMc,TestMc];
var randomValue:Number  =  Math.random()*1;
var randMc:Class = randMcs[randomValue] as Class;
var myRandMc:MovieClip=new randMc() as MovieClip;
```

Hope it will help you !

Comment: Thats really useful thanks. Been trying to figure that one out all day. Now just gotta figure out how to score it :/